# Error: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, token, azure-ad-msal, asp.net-core-6.0

I am attempting to make a basic Microsoft Graph API call but I get this error whenever I call the `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync()` function to get a token. This is an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application.

Program.cs:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

appSettings.json:

```
"MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
},
```

Controller:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "user.read" })]
public class UserManagementController : Controller
{
    ...
    [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "user.read" })]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        try
        {
             var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "user.read" });
             return View();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("An error occurred loading the user management page.");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried many solutions to this. The error is always the same:

> An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

I'm just trying to get the basics working, nothing fancy.

Comment: Before you go to `public async Task<IActionResult> Index()` method, did you sign in with your ms account? If yes,  pls try to using private mode/clear the cookie and test again.

Comment: Basically, you need to sign in first and then you can trying to execute `_tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` to get access token

Comment: Yes, I am signed in.

Answer (score 0):

Pls allow me share an example here.

At first, let's adding ms identity ui, create a partial view named `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in `Views/Shared` folder.

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

Then adding the partial view into `_Layout.cshtml` : `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />`

[image]

Then in the `Program.cs`, set the azure ad authentication by following code, and adding `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();`:

```
string[]? initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

These require following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.25.1" />
```

Then in `appsettings.json`, adding properties like below:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "azure_ad_client_id",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
```

Then adding `[Authorize]` for the home controller so that it will ask you to sign in before rendering index page.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "user.read" });
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have all these items thanks.

Comment: @Cef did you find a solution for this? i am running into this issue with Blazor Server graph API integration, .net 7

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am in the middle of a MS support ticket and even they can't seem to find the problem.